# Is there a way to add watermark to all videos in Google Drive’s folder?

Tags: google-apps-script, ffmpeg, google-drive-api, watermark, video-watermarking

Is there a way to add watermark to all videos in Google Drive’s folder?

I found similar service, but it works only with pictures, pdfs - [Wappwolf](http://wappwolf.com/dropboxautomator)

Maybe, it's possible to do by Google Apps Script or some other services (like ffmpeg)?

Comment: Is [Youtube](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6147757?hl=en) an option? Otherwise, I think you have to add the water mark before uploading it to drive. There's lots of software and tutorials for it online.

Comment: Thank you @Andy for your comment. If I use "Youtube's Branding watermark feature" - after downloading it from youtube there is no watermark, so I'm looking for other solution.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Are you asking How to watermark a video? If so, what does this have to do with google?

Comment: The relatiom with google I guess is that he asks if its doable with a google api since its stored in drive. The answer to that is no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its stored in drive, but there is no google api that does that with a drive file. In particular for images in drive you cannot change anything except its drive metadata/title unless you reupload new data yourself.